# Why is it impossible to liquefy a gas with only pressure?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, gas-laws, theoretical-chemistry, phase

Why is it impossible to turn it to liquid by using only pressure after it reaches critical temperature? What happens in the molecular level? If we put enough pressure, the molecules are supposed to come close enough to become liquid. Then why it is impossible?

Comment: Why, it **is** possible with *some* gases.

Comment: With some gases... *at some temperatures.* You have to be below the critical temperature for the particular gas.